What is the likelihood of tossing a bent coin *up to 2 times* and getting a HEAD on the *last* toss
Suppose I have a bent coin where the probability of getting HEAD is $q$, and tails is $1-q$. Then I set up the following game:

You may toss the coin up to two times. Only the last toss counts.
If you terminate the toss on a TAIL, then you win. Otherwise you lose.

Clearly I would play by tossing the coin once, so that if it lands TAIL, then I stop on the first toss. If I see HEAD, then I toss again and report what ever comes up this 2nd time. So there are three possible toss sequences:
\begin{align*}
HT   \\ T \_ \\ HH 
\end{align*}
Now from this set of outcomes, I can construct a new coin with bias $p$, where prob of head is $p$. The question is what is the value of this $p$? I can think of two lines of reasoning.

Naively I'd say $p=\frac{1}{3}$, by simply inspecting the possible outcomes. The problem is that one of the sequence $T\_$ only has one toss in it, while the other two sequences have two tosses: $HH$ and $HT$. So I'm not sure how write this formally.

In the second line of reasoning, I'd write down the likelihood of each sequence as a function of $q$ with:


\begin{align*}
HT &: q \cdot (1-q)
 \\ 
T \_ &: 1-q
\\ HH &: q^2
\end{align*}
And then normalize so that, ie the probability of $HT$ is:
\begin{align*}
prob(HT) = \frac{q(1-q)}{
q(1-q) + (1-q) + q^2
}
\end{align*}
Then I'd say $prob(HEAD) = \frac{prob(HH)}{prob(HH) + prob(HT) + prob(T)}$. Which line of reasoning is correct? I'm inclined to say the 2nd one, but I an also justify the first one.

Proposal 1. is straightforward to reject. It assumes that the three outcomes are equally likely, but there is nothing to support that modelling assumption.
Modelling things as equally likely typically requires some form of symmetry to show that the various events are somehow equivalent.
Proposal 2. is correct.
However, you are making a conceptual mistake when you normalize. You are computing the probability of a set of events which are:

exclusive: only a single one can happen.
exhaustive: one event is guaranteed to occur.

Thus, the total probability should be one.
We should thus check, to make sure that we haven't done anything wrong, that the sum of their probabilities is equal to 1, as it should. With your equations, we indeed have:
$$
p(\text{T_}) + p(\text{HH}) + p(\text{HT}) = 1
$$
and we find the probability of winning by summing:
$$
p(\text{Win}) = p(\text{T_}) + p(\text{HT}) = 1 - q^2
$$
Here a two simple further sanity checks:

as the probability of heads goes down, this tends to 1.
this is higher than the probability of winning on the first throw.

